# Flex Certificate .crt file into ByteArray for secureSocket class addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate method

Tags: apache-flex, security, certificate

I have a certificate file which I want to import into flex application to establish a secure socket connection with a sever. But I am a getting an exception which says `ArgumentError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid`.

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("xyz.crt");
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doEvent);
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
urlLoader.load(request);

private function doEvent(evt:Event):void {
var ldr:URLLoader = evt.target as URLLoader;
secureSocket.addEventListener( Event.CONNECT, onConnect )
secureSocket.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError );
try {
  secureSocket.addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate(ldr.data,true );
  secureSocket.connect( "192.168.2.100", 443 );
} catch ( error:Error ) {
  Alert.show( error.toString() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason is because the certificat is encoded in PEM format.
After convert it into DER format, it works fine.

> A ByteArray object containing a DER-encoded X.509 digital certificate.